# Javac compile arguments

Tags: java, javac

I'm doing [this tutorial](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html) and I'm stuck at the last part.

```
$ javac -cp target/apt-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Test.java
Note: Printing: Test
Note: Printing: a1(int)
```

Running it just says "javac: file not found Test.java" (I downloaded the source from github, so it's identical.)

Comment: Well, is there a file called "Test.java" in the directory in which you are running the javac command?

Comment: Yes, there is a file.

Comment: Use `javac -cp target/apt-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;. Test.java`

Comment: Some filesystems are case sensitive.  Are you sure the file name is Test.java and not test.java?

Comment: If the source file is in your directory and is called "Test.java" then that command should work.  Normally when I see a target directory, I think maven, in which case your source would be src/main/java/some/package/Test.java, not local to the root dir.  Can you post the output of a directory listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify package also.

```
$ javac -cp target/apt-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar your package.Test.java
```

Comment: Looks like `Test.java` is not in any package.